# truffle console - invoking contract function usage (Version 3)

Tags: solidity, truffle

I have a simple contract like below. I was able to successfully compile and migrate the same.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract A {

    function A() payable {
    }

    function getBal() returns(uint a){
        return (10);
    }

}
```

Now I am using truffle console and trying to invoke `getBal()` function of my contract.

```
A.deployed().then(function(instance) { test = instance; return test.getBal();}).then(function(result){});
```

I am not getting the new version 3 way of calling the functions.

Could you help me out and point what I am missing?

[image: console window]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this.

```
function getBal() 
  public
  constant   <--- Important
  returns(uint a)
{
  return (10);
}
```

$ truffle console

```
   > A.deployed()
    .then(function(instance) {
      return instance.getBal();
    })
    .then(function(balance) {
      console.log("got balance", balance.toString(10));
    });
```

I'm not fully acquainted with Truffle 0.3 myself, but it seems to work :-)

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Rob. I tried the above way but I am not getting the output. I am attaching the screen shot of the result

Answer (score 2):

in truffle develop you can use a contract function, on a contract that has been deployed, by:

**"ContractName.at("ContractAddress").FunctionName(FunctionArguments)**

example

```
truffle(develop)> A.at("0x842c27notcopyablescreenshot4bf7dd").getBal()
```

this will give you something like

> { [String: '10'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 10 ] }

you can find the address by going up to when the contract was first deployed

OR

By running the command `ContractName.address` at truffle console.

Example output:

`truffle(development)> Migrations.address
'0x0045b992bafe7362e65c34ad5153fad4a2695c1f'
truffle(development)>`

OR

by opening up a 2nd terminal in the same place and typing.

```
$ truffle networks
```